# Can this sum be defined? $\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^\frac{N}{4} \frac{1}{(N-2n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The alternating harmonic series is 1-1/2+1/3-1/4+1/5-1/6+1/7-1/8+... I am trying to see if I can eliminate the last N/4 positive terms.

For instance, if the above were just a partial sum of the AHS (no "+..."), I would eliminate 1/5 and 1/7. When the number of terms grows to infinity, the number of terms I need to lop off has an infinite number of terms as well (N/4). Strangely enough, this series converges (and it's greater than zero) even though it belongs to the divergent series of all positive terms. But from a theoretical point of view I am a bit stumped because as N tends to infinity, I need to define a series of positive terms $\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^\frac{N}{4} \frac{1}{(N-2n+1)}$ where none of the terms seem to exist because I cannot even define which would be the first term. What do you think?

(the terms of this series are as described for any N multiple of 4,

Comment: The terms of this series are as described for any N multiple of 4, zero otherwise. Note that the first term would be, for n=1, $\frac{1}{(N-1)}$ and the last term, for n=N/4, $\frac{1}{(N/2+1)}$ so both are infinitely far away in the AHS.

Answer (score 2):

By Riemann sums
$$\lim_{M\to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{M}\frac{1}{4M-2n+1}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{4-2x}=\color{red}{\log\sqrt{2}}$$
as well as
$$ \sum_{1\leq n\leq\frac{N}{4}}\frac{1}{N-2n+1}=\log\sqrt{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right) $$
no matter what $N\pmod{4}$ is, as soon as $N$ is large enough.

Comment: Thank you! although I think is ln, not log.

Comment: @paulhawkey Mathematicians often use $\log$ to denote the logarithm with base $e$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\lim_{N \to \infty}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor\, N/4\, \right\rfloor}{1 \over N - 2n + 1}} =
\lim_{N \to \infty}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor\, N/4\, \right\rfloor}\int_{0}^{1}x^{N - 2n}
\,\,\,\dd x =
\lim_{N \to \infty}\,\,\int_{0}^{1}x^{N}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor\, N/4\, \right\rfloor}\pars{x^{-2}}^{n}
\,\,\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{N \to \infty}\,\,\int_{0}^{1}
{x^{N - 2\left\lfloor\, N/4\, \right\rfloor}\,\,\,\,\,\, -\,\,\, x^{N} \over
1 - x^{2}}\,\,\,\dd x =
\half\,\lim_{N \to \infty}\,\,\int_{0}^{1}
{x^{N/2 - \left\lfloor\, N/4\, \right\rfloor - 1/2}\,\,\,\,\,\, -
\,\,\, x^{N/2 - 1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\,\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\half\,\lim_{N \to \infty}\,\,\,\bracks{\Psi\pars{{N \over 2} + \half} -
\Psi\pars{{N \over 2} - \left\lfloor\,{N \over 4}\, \right\rfloor +
\half}\vphantom{\Huge A^{a}}}\quad\quad
\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\lim_{N \to \infty}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor\, N/4\, \right\rfloor}{1 \over N - 2n + 1}} =
\half\,\lim_{N \to \infty}\,
\ln\pars{N/2  \over N/2 - \left\lfloor\, N/4\, \right\rfloor}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\half\,\lim_{N \to \infty}
\ln\pars{1 - {\left\lfloor\, N/4\, \right\rfloor \over N/2}} =
-\,\half\,\ln\pars{1 - \half} = 
\color{#f00}{\half\,\ln\pars{2}} \approx 0.3466
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{\Psi\pars{z + \half} \sim \ln\pars{z}  + {1 \over 24z^{2}} - {7 \over 960z^{4}} +
> {31 \over 8064z^{6}} + \cdots\quad}$ as $\ds{\verts{z} \to \infty}$ with
>   $\ds{\,\verts{\mrm{arg}\pars{z}} < \pi}$.

Comment: @paulhawkey You're welcome. Glad it was helpful to you.

Comment: As witnessed by the "miraculous" cancellations at the end, none of this détour is necessary, really. To invoke the digamma function in this context is (tiring and) to use a sledgehammer to kill a fly.

Comment: @Did You are quite right. However, the 'easy one' was already ( or simultaneously ) worked out by $\texttt{Jack D'Aurizio}$.

Comment: Since you are systematically flooding the site with these digamma-tricks and a few related ones (and with next to nothing else), @Jack's answer is not the reason you posted yours and you know it. So much for candor.